# winform designer loading failed

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2005

I have wrote a winform control with vs2005.

This control is inherited from UserControl. At first, it worked well. But after some time, error occured when load winform designer.

The error message is below:

`"NameCaption"` isn't the property of type `"System.Windows.Forms.UserControl"`.

Here is the define of `NameCaption`:

```
public string NameCaption  
{  
    get  
    {  
        return this._nameCondCaption;  
    }  
    set  
    {  
        this._nameCondCaption = value;  
        this.nameLabel.Text = value;  
    }  
}  
private string _nameCondCaption = "Name";
```

I think `NameCaption` is not the root cause.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you trying to cast your user control to UserControl class? like this UserControl ctrl = MyUserControl, then ctrl.NamedCaption? something like this?

Comment: I didn't make such cast.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code like this:

```
public string NameCaption  
{  
    get  
    {  
        return this.nameLabel.Text;  
    }  
    set  
    {  
        this.nameLabel.Text = value;  
    }  
}  
private string _nameCondCaption = "Name";
```

Now it works. But I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making it hidden to the designer serialization using the [`DesignerSerializationVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibility.aspx) attribute like this:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public string NameCaption  
{  
    get  
    {  
        return this._nameCondCaption;  
    }  
    set  
    {  
        this._nameCondCaption = value;  
        this.nameLabel.Text = value;  
    }  
}  
private string _nameCondCaption = "Name";
```